# How to align an element within a div to be even across the others in a row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I'm having difficulty trying to align the three icon containers that are presented in the row. I tried a combination of `flex-end` and `baseline` but they did not work, neither on the `img` tags or the `h3` tags within the container. Here's what I have in code as well as a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/95593/):

Edit: I want to be able to align the image to the bottom of the div, so the content is even. I remember getting it right before with flexbox, forgot how it was done. It was some variation of using the properties I've already tried but maybe I'm using them wrong? Not entirely sure!

```css
.icons {
  display: inline-flex;
}
.icons img {
  vertical-align: baseline;
  align-self: flex-end;
  align-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.icons h3 {
  vertical-align: baseline;
  align-self: baseline;
  align-content: baseline;
  align-items: baseline;
  justify-content: baseline;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="icons">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="icon">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/88x131"/>
        <h3>Header 1</h3>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="icon">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/116x98"/>
        <h3>Header 2</h3>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="icon">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/107x116"/>
        <h3>Header 3</h3>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitl Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the `row` class in bootstrap to put the images on their own row.
(Probably need to adjust to put in some col-sm classes but this might get you started)

```css
.icons img {
    vertical-align: baseline;
    align-self: flex-end;
    align-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.icons h3 {
    vertical-align: baseline;
    align-self: baseline;
    align-content: baseline;
    align-items: baseline;
    justify-content: baseline;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.bottom-align {
    height: 150px;
}

.bottom-align img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
  <div class="icons">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 bottom-align">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/88x131">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 bottom-align">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/116x98">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 bottom-align">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/107x116">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="icon">
        <h3>Header 1</h3>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="icon">
        <h3>Header 2</h3>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="icon">
        <h3>Header 3</h3>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitl Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not what I'm looking for exactly. I want to align the image at least to the bottom of the div right before the header or at least the header to have some type of baseline, so it's even across the other two.

Comment: Updated to align to bottom with position absolute and a set height

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/95598/

You can wrap images in a div and assign divs a class (myImg):

```css
.icons {
  display: flex;
}

.myImg {
  height: 140px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="icons">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="icon">
        <div class="myImg">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/88x131"/>
        </div>
        <h3>Header 1</h3>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="icon">
        <div class="myImg">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/116x98"/>
        </div>
        <h3>Header 2</h3>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="icon">
        <div class="myImg">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/107x116"/>
        </div>
        <h3>Header 3</h3>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitl Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

then use **min-height**, can also set divs' images `min-width` if you want images of same height too (they resize thought so consider using object-fit:cover or even better setting images as background and then using background-size: cover;)

Comment: I don't want to adjust image height. I want to align the image at least to the bottom of the div right before the header or at least the header to have some type of baseline, so it's even across the other two.

Comment: Edited, you can add display: flex to myImg class, and align-self: flex-end .